# Show that $\pi \cot \pi z = \frac{1}{z} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 z}{z^2 - n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

This question has been asked before, but we are supposed to prove for any $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ that $$\pi \cot \pi z = \frac{1}{z} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 z}{z^2 - n^2}$$ using the fact that $$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2 \pi z} = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$$ If we can integrate the RHS of the above expression term by term, we see that for a constant $C$: $$\pi \cot \pi z = C+  \frac{1}{z} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 z}{z^2 - n^2}$$ So my first question would be how to go about showing that $C = 0$.  It seems difficult to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2z}{z^2 - n^2}$ in general.

But my main question is how to show we can integrate term by term in the first place.  As I understand it, this is allowed if we show that $g(z) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ is uniformly and absolutely convergent on arbitrary compact sets $K \subseteq \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

> If $K$ consists only of real numbers, we can argue as follows:

For every $x \in K$, there is a unique $\epsilon = \epsilon_x \in (0,1)$ for which $x - \epsilon$ is an integer.  Thus $g(z) = g(\epsilon)$ by shifting.  Furthermore since $K$ is compact, it is easy to see that there exists an $\eta \in (0,1)$ such that $\eta < \epsilon_x < 1 - \eta$ for all $x \in K$.

When $n \geq 2$, we get $|\epsilon - n| \geq n-1$, and when $n \leq -1$, we get $|\epsilon - n| \geq n$.  Thus for $g(z) = g(\epsilon) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(\epsilon-n)^2}$, we have $$\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{|\epsilon - n|^2} = \frac{1}{|\epsilon|^2} + \frac{1}{|\epsilon-1|^2} + \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|\epsilon - n|^2} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|\epsilon + n|^2}$$ $$ \leq \frac{2}{\eta^2} + \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)^2} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$ Thus $g(z)$ converges uniformly on $K$ by the M-test.

> How can I show the same result when $K$ is not necessarily contained in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: To prove $C=0$, it is enough to evaluate both sides in $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: So, show that $0 = 2 + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{4} - n^2}$

Comment: the sum telescopes

Comment: Ah of course, thanks.  Now I just have to figure out the last part.